# looking into the recent time logs

Tags: unix

I have to monitor a several logs file which I do mostly by tails -f command but now I want that when i tail the logs it should show me  the logs of 10 mins before as I do not want to see the logs 
of all the time which are even 1 hour old i, i just want to see the latest logs of 20 mins before below is the snapshot that how the logs are recorded

```
18-Oct-2013 20:05.58.878 ERROR [NDC=] [BIBCO  (2954357666681)] com.abc.def.ghtimpl There was a problem commiting the resource null
```

Comment: You can use grep to show logs within last hour

Comment: @bksi can you please advise how to achieve..!

Comment: tail -f somefile.log | grep 18-Oct-2013 20:    will give you last changes from 20:00 of 18.Oct.2013

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood your question. When you do tail -f it starts showing the live logs and no way it will print the previous logs. See if these articles are of help to you. There are many ways given to play with the log files using grep , awk , sed , tail etc.